# File upload using angular js in lotus notes html form

Tags: json, angularjs, file-upload, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am using lotus notes form as .html files and I am sending values to server as json using angular js. But I want to upload files also now. How can I send files to server and extract using lotus script?

Can you please help me someone?

Like the below post. But it is done in ASP.NET . I want to do the same using lotus notes.

[File uploading angular js ASP .NET](http://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/)

**index.html**

```
<span ng-if="quests.type == '17'">
<input type="file" file-upload multiple id='{{quests.id}}'/>
</span>

<button type="button" ng-click="submitForm();">Submit</button>
```

The above button will trigger the below code to executed.

**Angular Code to post to server**

```
var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
var message={"requesttype": "saveForm","email": emailid,"username": username};
$http.post("http://test.com/ajaxprocess?openagent", message).success(success).error(failure);
```

The above mentioned agent(lotusscript) will parse the above json and save the document as shown below.

**ajaxprocess Agent code**

```
'getting document context
Set docContext = sess.DocumentContext
If docContext.hasItem("REQUEST_CONTENT") Or docContext.hasItem("REQUEST_CONTENT_000") Then
    'using openNTF lotus script classes to parse document to json object
    Set userDataInfo=getJSONObjectFromDocument(docContext, "")
    Dim fieldsobj As New JSONArray
    'getting the fields array sent as json array
    Set fieldsobj=userDataInfo.GetItemValue("fields")
    fieldtype=Field.mGetItemValue("type")(0)
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim fieldname As String
    ForAll Field In fieldsobj.Items
        fieldname=Field.mGetItemValue("Fieldname")(0)
        Call doc.Replaceitemvalue(fieldname,Field.mGetItemValue("value")(0))
    End ForAll
    call doc.save(true,false)
End If
```

Everything works fine expect file attachments. How can I send files to server with json and save using lotus script or is there any other workaround is there?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you have written to attempt this and tell uw what happened.

Comment: Hi Richard,Thanks for the response.  I have edited the post. Please have a look.

Comment: Your Angular code references an agent called ajaxprocess. Where is that agent? Show the source code you have tried.

Comment: I have posted server code above. Now I am sending all the field types (text,date,time) and able to save the document. But I am not able to achieve file upload using the above code, since I dont know the method to upload and decode the attachments. Please let me know if it is not clear. Thank you for your precious time for helping me. very much appreciated.

Comment: So, is the problem that file attachment being sent to the server as a json fieldname/value pair, but you don't know how to save it in the document on the Domino server? Or is the problem that the file attachnment is not being sent to the server?

Comment: Yes Richard. I want to send the file attachment with json or some other method to server and save on domino server using lotus script . I don't know how to send the attachment or save on domino server either.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with what you need to do on the browser side with angular.js. I do know that if you want to actually store it so that it will be seen by Domino as an attachment, you'll have to do more processing in your LotusScript code - but if it's not even uploading for you that's not relevant. I've upvoted the question, and maybe someone who knows angular will be able to assist.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I have put this on hold untill I get some tips . I am doing others stuffs.

Comment: Hi Vijayakumar - is the requirement simply to send file attachments to Domino from a web page, or must it work inside an angular script?

Comment: Yes Carter. We have to send file attachments to domino server without using lotus notes design element(No binding in lotus notes form). Simply, there is upload field in .html file, we have to upload the attachments to domino server. I am uploading text data now using angular ajax and finding the way to do the file attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found tip and made the solution as follows to get the base64 String and convert to attachment in lotusscript.

*http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/dx/creating-a-mime-email-with-attachment?opendocument&comments*

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
 Dim stream As NotesStream
 Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity
 Dim header As NotesMIMEHeader
 Dim StringInBase64 As String
 StringInBase64=getbase64() 'your base64 string
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
 Set db=s.Currentdatabase
 Dim tempdoc As NotesDocument
Set tempdoc=db.Createdocument()
Set stream = s.CreateStream
Call stream.WriteText(StringInBase64)
Set body = tempdoc.CreateMIMEEntity
Set header = body.createHeader("content-disposition")
Call header.setHeaderVal({attachment;filename="Onchange.xlsx"}) ' file name and type should be configurable
Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "", ENC_BASE64)
Call stream.Close
tempdoc.form="Attachment"
Call tempdoc.save(True,False)
```

This works as expected. Thanks all for time you spent.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for Multiple attachments, enhancement from Vijayakumar.

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set doc = db.CreateDocument
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim stream As NotesStream   
    Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim child As NotesMimeEntity
    Dim header As NotesMIMEHeader
    Set body =  doc.CreateMIMEEntity


    topString = Split(BASE64, ",")

    Dim tmp_array() As String
    i = 0

    For i = 0 To Ubound(topString)
        Redim Preserve tmp_array(i)
        tmp_array(i) = topString(i)


        Set child = body.CreateChildEntity()
        Set header = child.CreateHeader("Content-Type")
        Call header.SetHeaderVal("multipart/mixed") 
        Set header =child.createHeader("Content-Disposition")
        Call header.setHeaderVal({attachment; filename=test} &Cstr(i)& {.jpg}) 'file name and type should be configure


        Set header =child.CreateHeader("Content-ID")
        Call header.SetHeaderVal("test" &Cstr(i)& ".jpg")

        Set stream = s.CreateStream()
        Call stream.WriteText(topString(i))
        Call child.SetContentFromText(stream, "", ENC_BASE64)

    Next

    doc.form="Attachment"
    'doc.Attachment = tmp_array 
    Call doc.save(True,False)
    Call stream.Close() 
    s.ConvertMIME = True ' Restore conversion
```